# How to use grepl function to subset rows based on multiple conditions across columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I am trying to subset a dataset using the `grepl` function.

I want to retain rows where all columns contain '@'

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
all_nullx <- riv %>% with(riv, riv[ grepl( '@', col1) & grepl( '@', col2) & grepl('@', col3) & grepl('@', left_index) & grepl('@', right_middle) & grepl('@', col4), ])
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share part of your dataset?

Comment: To share your dataset, you can type `dput(riv)` into the console, then copy and then  paste into your question here. If it's a long dataset, then you can just provide part of it by using `head`, i.e., `dput(head(riv))`.

Comment: Why are you passing `riv` into `with` twice?

Answer (score 3):

**Tidyverse**

We can apply a function across all columns using `everything()` inside of `across`, then keep only rows that have `@` in every column.

```
library(tidyverse)

riv %>% 
  filter(across(everything(), ~ grepl("@", .)))
```

Or with `stringr`:

```
riv %>% 
  filter(across(everything(), ~ str_detect(., "@")))
```

**base R**

Or we can use `grepl` with `Reduce` from `base R`:

```
riv[Reduce(`&`, lapply(riv, grepl, pattern = "@")),]
```

Or one more base R possibility:

```
riv[apply(riv , 1 , function(x) all(grepl("@", x))), ]
```

**Output**

```
    a   b   c
1 A@r C@r F@r
2 B@r D@r G@r
```

**Data**

```
riv <- structure(list(
  a = c("A@r", "B@r", "Rr"),
  b = c("C@r", "D@r", "E@r"),
  c = c("F@r", "G@r", "Hr")
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

one nice option within the `tidyverse`, specifically `dplyr` in this case, can be the [`if_all()`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/) function (I will use @andrews data)

```
riv <- structure(list(
  a = c("A@r", "B@r", "Rr"),
  b = c("C@r", "D@r", "E@r"),
  c = c("F@r", "G@r", "Hr")
),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-3L))

library(dplyr)

riv %>%
     dplyr::filter(if_all(everything(), ~grepl("@", .x)))

    a   b   c
1 A@r C@r F@r
2 B@r D@r G@r
```